# Correct way to implement cascading dropdowns in Spring MVC 3.2.x

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to figure out the correct/optimal way to implement dropdowns using Spring MVC 3.2.x. I have JSP page with 4 dropdowns, 2 cascading and 1 static. Here is the **typical implementation that works:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employeeSearch")
public class EmployeeSearchController {
.......
@ModelAttribute("employeeOrgList")
public List<EmployeeOrgList> populateOrgList(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return employeeService.getEmployeeOrgList();
}

@ModelAttribute("employeeSubOrg1List")
public List<EmployeeSubOrg1List> populateSubOrg1List(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return employeeService.getEmployeeSubOrg1List();
}

@ModelAttribute("employeeSubOrg2List")
public List<EmployeeSubOrg2List> populateSubOrg2List(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return employeeService.getEmployeeSubOrg2List();
}

@ModelAttribute("employeeStatusList")
public List<EmployeeStatusList> populateStatusList(HttpServletRequest request) {
   return employeeService.getEmployeeStatusList();
}

...............
```

**The PROBLEM:**
In above implementations, user chooses employee org list first, page refreshes to populate employee sub org 1 list and when employee selects sub org 1 then sub org 2 is populated and employee status dropdown remains populated. This code works just fine as is. But the PROBLEM is I have 7 RequestMappings in the EmployeeSearchController, including the ones that deal with dropdown selections. So, for every call, I'm hitting database **7 x 4 = 28** times, which i think is unacceptable.

To address the issue I removed @ModelAttribute on all 4 methods and manually added them to the model when the pages is accessed for the first time (RequestMapping set to GET). The JSP loads fine but as soon as I select the employee org list, the employee sub org 1 list gets populated but employee org list and employee status lists are blank. Here are the specific methods:

```
//This is to initialize
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public ModelAndView handlePageEntry(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap) {
    EmployeeSearchForm form = new EmployeeSearchForm();
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("employeeSearchTile");
    modelView.addAttribute("form", form);
    modelView.addAttribute("employeeOrgList", getEmployeeOrgList());
    modelView.addAttribute("employeeSubOrg1ist", new ArrayList<EmployeeSubOrg1ist>());
    modelView.addAttribute("employeeSubOrg2ist", new ArrayList<EmployeeSubOrg1ist>());
    modelView.addAttribute("employeeStatusList", getEmployeeStatusList());
    return modelView;
}

//This one is called when we select employee org list
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, params = { "submitAction=employeeOrgSelected" })
public ModelAndView populateEmployeeSubOrg1(@ModelAttribute(value = "form") EmployeeSearchForm form, ModelMap modelMap) {
   ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("employeeSearchTile");
    modelView.addAttribute("form", form);
    modelView.addAttribute("employeeSubOrg1ist", getEmployeeSubOrg1ist(form.getSelectedEmployeeOrg));
    return modelView;
}
```

Obviously, I'm neither adding the employee org and employee status list back to the model nor am i setting them up in session (which I do not want to do). And If I want to set them on the model then I've to hit the the database again for those 2 lists. Its better than hitting 28 times but still I want the experts to weigh-in.

SO what is the best way to accomplish this task without so many trips to the database?

Comment: You might want to look into Ajax so you don't have to reload the whole page each time one dropdown is changed.

Comment: Thank you @developerwjk , Ajax is one possible solution but I cannot use it as the site needs to be 'accessible' (508 compliant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alleviate database trips you can:

a) If the information is relational and you can use joins to get what you need, try bringing back more information with less queries.

b) You can cache the service call results. I generally use ehcache w/ Spring annotations for this: Then you're just caching in one place instead of everyone's session

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "employeeDataCache")
public List<EmployeeOrgList> getEmployeeSubOrg1List() {
   // do whatever
}
```

https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/UsingCacheable

Comment: I was afraid it would be caching that I would have to rely on. I'm guessing there is no Spring MVC recommended way of dealing with the problem. I cannot up-vote as i don't have reputations. I'll accept your solution unless someone else have any other ideas.

Comment: You could have a bean, say "EmployeeData". which contains getSubOrgList(), getStatusList(), etc and just use @ModelAttribute with that.  You'd obviously still need to make the database calls to get that data.  There's really no way around it without getting the data each time, or caching it.  Caching in the session is a no-no if the data is the same between users so that's why I recommend the ehcache approach.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and I agree with your recommendation.